# Allow personal messaging to pro members of stack community?

Tags: feature-request, status-declined

Pro members of stack community have great knowledge to answer most of the queries which are asked by users. Not only I want to subscribe to their every answer and comment they upload I also want to message them if I want a specific answer. Neither of the feature is available.

Comment: Both features have been requested before, and declined. The short answer is (a) SE is not a social network, we prefer, to the extent possible, to focus on content, not people, and (b) we don't want to overwhelm already-highly-visible users with dozens and scores of questions from people who "just want answers".

Comment: Is it possible to display their email on their profile if some pros want to make it visible?

Comment: Don't you think people would me messaging them all day? No thanks.

Comment: @user334283 That's already possible; anyone can put his email address in his profile page. But you'll note that no one chooses to do that. Imagine if you were one of these "pros", getting dozens of emails a day from strangers. Would you want that?

Comment: I'm getting addicted to this community and I'm becoming a fan of those experts more than any famous celebrity. I just don't want to let them go. They are like my professors now.

Comment: @DanBron If I was a pro, I would leave my email on my profile and try to assist every possible questions though it may take days.

Comment: @user334283 Then I encourage you to practice until you're a pro and then do just that. But be warned: it won't just take days, it'll be a lifetime commitment. The emails will never stop.

Comment: @DanBron It'll take me 4yrs to be like them and as you can see web technologies are changing very fast. I'm sure after 4yrs Stack exchange will have video conferencing and tutorials.On that day I would just imagine that if that could have existed in past.

Comment: @user334283 When I was learning this stuff, there was no internet at all. Imagine that!

Comment: @DanBron What you are saying is right though. I just have to admit it. But I hope stack exchange will keep on advancing itself and they may consider subscribing members one day.

Comment: Shorter OP: How can I stalk other members?

Comment: @user334283 as one of those "pros" I would disable the feature and change my email to filter all email to go into trash.  If I want to help I submit an answer, if I don't, no answer.

Answer (score 3):

Folks often throw around the phrase *"Stack Exchange is not a social network"* … but what that ***really*** means is it is NOT the mission of this site to have folks meet up and solve their problems privately.

The entire purpose of Stack Exchange is to create a *public* resource. Folks ask questions in a public venue and the participants share the best solutions for the benefit of everyone *else* who may run into that same problem. Stack Exchange is a collaborative resource for sharing knowlege — so it makes little sense to allow folks to solicit answers offline which will **benefit no one else** at all.

Everything we do is in full view of the public.

Comment: But you can ask only limited questions per topic. If you try to reply with more questions based on previously answered comments then community has to alert the user that "this is not a discussion site". That leaves the user with little doubt for that topic. I've also faced this.

Comment: @user334283 That's why not all questions are a good fit for a Stack Exchange site. This type of Q&A is not a discussion forum, so if the question cannot be answered correctly and completely in the space of a post, it isn't likely a good fit for this site. That is why we don't allow questions that will likely start on-going debates or round table discussions. Stack Exchange was designed explicitly to avoid these types of *"we'll arrive at the correct answer eventually..."* That's what makes SE different than discussion forums... even if that premise does not appeal to everyone.

Comment: It shouldn't be called "discussion". It's more like "clearing" that  doubt which is raised with an answer. Does Stack Exchange support "doubt clearing"?

Comment: @user334283 Yes, every post allows 'comments' which are meant to ask for clarification or to otherwise suggest improvements to the post. But comments are not for answers, so whatever information is contained in the comments should be edited back into the original post (if warranted) and the comments removed. They are not an intrinsic part of the answer itself.